# Network Render missing objects

Tags: rendering, network

For the past 12 hours today, I was trying to use the Blender Network Render using the Blender Internal Render Engine. Now, I made sure I saved every thing before I started using it, but instead of getting the same result from just using the Internal Render engine like this:

[image: Portal with a Particle System]

I'm getting an image that looks like this instead.

[image: Just an ordinary portal with no Particle System.]

Both of the images are png files and I have done every thing from making sure I baked the particle system to sending the job and Animating and Baking on the Network. I really don't know here I went wrong. So I'm hoping, yet again, to get some answers.

Comment: Okay, so not much has changed in my situation. I also keep getting exr files after the process. That is something I have no need for. Still looking for the png files.

Comment: Update: The problem, as it turns out, that the Network Render is only rendering 1 of the layers instead of all of the layers. Still need to figure this problem out.

Comment: Update: Actual problem identified. When switching to the Network Render Engine from the Blender Internal Render Engine, it takes away the depth socket from 2 of the layers. Possible masking effect could be rendered useless.

Comment: Update: Now the program is telling me that no such directory exist. I've tried using another render farm program, didn't like it and now the Network Render add on is screwed up.

Comment: Update: It currently keeps saying "No such file or directory C:\\User\\Name\\Temp\\" Etc...

Comment: Update: Now, I need to find a way to convert the EXR images into PNG files after testing the addon on a different file. It turns out it was the file and not the addon acting up. Greaaaaaaaat...

Comment: Update: Now, I'm back to square one with the original question.

Comment: Update: Issue solved with Network Render issue resolved with one other method. Now, I have to figure out how to get all of the frames that were shown through this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3EcpkwLCFI